# 'IF' Statement Not Working Properly (Pinescript)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am trying to use an if statement to make my projections better in pinescript. However, the IF statement isn't working has it's supposed too.

The statement:

```
NCV = if close < companyValue and bias_on
    companyValue = companyValue - bias
else
    companyValue = totalNPVFCF + year10FCFValue + cashAndEquivalents - totalLiabilities
```

When I plug this in, it will use the "CompanyValue - bias" for the entire thing when bias is on, instead of just when CompanyValue is above close, and bias is on.

Screenshots:

[Without Bias On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bqzV.png)

[With Bias On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlxqo.png)

I've tried switching the <> signs, and flipping the "if" statement, but neither worked.

Comment: I'm confused. it says in the post. I guess I can type it out. if company value is greater than close and bias is on, than company value equals company value minus bias. else, company value is totalNPVFCF + year10FCFValue + cashAndEquivalents - totalLiabilities. So in other words, where the close is greater than company value, it should be totalNPVFCF + year10FCFValue + cashAndEquivalents - totalLiabilities, but it's not.

Comment: What is that plot? Is it `NCV` or `companyValue`?

Comment: the plot is NCV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NCV = close < companyValue and bias_on ? companyValue - bias : totalNPVFCF + year10FCFValue + cashAndEquivalents - totalLiabilities
```

This should do what you where asking in the comments.

I am still wondering why no rule when `bias` is `false`, cause this would change the whole calculation I guess.

**Explanation...**

You where using `variable = if else` which will create a locale scope where you edited the value of `companyValue`. I changed it to a one-liner which wont change `companyValue` at all and the return value will be `NCV`. For your approach the return value of `NCV` I am not sure what it would be, cause there is missing part in the code to find that out. Anyway, my assumption is you wont edit `companyValue` at all and use `NCV` to show the changes. This is what it should look like then.

**Addition...**

BTW when you have `companyValue` declared before, then you have to use `:=` to put a new value into an existing variable.

Comment: thank you! I greatly appreciate it! this explanation is really useful too.